# Icons are doubling in my panels

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, panel

Something is really screwed up with my panels. When I add icons, the next day some of them have doubled. When I remove one of the two icons, they both are deleted.

Any clues as to what is wrong?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the dock, or the top panel, or something else? A screenshot would be helpful. Do you accidentally have two dock extensions installed?

Comment: @heynnema Screenshot added.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu on VM? Screen resolution 1360x768 looks non-standard for physical hardware.

Comment: @N0rbert I am not running on VM.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to open MATE Tweak and change Layout of MATE Panels to Traditional and then back to your favorite. It will reset all the MATE Panels, so then you'll need to carefully place icons and applets in their places again.

Comment: I have tried it.